# ES6 import of dotenv/config

Tags: npm, ecmascript-6, dotenv, .env

Im using ES6 to import modules for React app, but having issues when importing the
`import "dotenv/config"`
After I place the import app crashes and i get this ERROR:

ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js 2:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/Users/Desktop/Developer/client/node_modules/dotenv/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
- install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "path": false }

WARNING: Do not store any secrets (such as private API keys) in your React app!

Environment variables are embedded into the build, meaning anyone can view them by inspecting your app's files.

Doc: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: dotenv is meant to be used in nodejs server applications, why are you trying to use it in a react app?

Comment: You have a great point as I'm not trying to store any key or secure code, but rather trying to set variables for my server ip address. I wonder if there's a way to hide it from someone inspecting the app's files. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Comment: A server IP address is public knowledge anyway, no need to hide that from anyone. (It might be worthwhile trying not to *hardcode* it)

Comment: Re create-react-app, that happens during build time. You would need to add `dotenv` to your build script, not to the app itself - and actually you don't even need that, since [the cra build script already loads `.env` files by default](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env)

Comment: In a situation like this, you might consider rolling your own.